How to copy project in Android Studio
I am making companion app for phone to assist in installing my watch face on a Wear OS watch. Each watch face needs its own phone app. These companion apps are essentially the same, with minor adjustments (e.g., package name).
What is the best way to duplicate projects in Android Studio, so I just have one template app that I can copy and update for each watch face?
Creating a new project and copy/pasting file contents is tedious.

If the differences are really minor, you can use flavors to achieve it - Configure product flavors. Most of the code will be in the main part and you can customize the needed parts - e.g. package name - per flavor.
Something like:
flavorDimensions += "watch"
productFlavors {
    create("type1") {
        applicationId "my.app.type1"
    }
    create("type2") {
        applicationId "my.app.type2"
    }
}

You can then choose your Active build variant for instance under Build Variants.

Very interesting idea, thank you! I will look into you more.
